# Attempting to read user input from jtextfield and display in another jtextfield. Comes up null

Tags: java, jtextfield, gettext

I am new to java and I just can't seem to solve this issue. I know I am missing something.

Basically what I am attempting to do is read the input from a user in a `JTextfield` and then display what the user entered into another `JTextfield`.

I want all this to occur after I hit the add button.  Once I hit the add button I want the user input from the first `JTextfield` to then be displayed in a different `JTextfield`.

However when in input something into the first text field and hit the add button I get a `null` value in the other `JTextfield`.  I can't figure out why.

I am using class variables that are supposed to store what the user inputs using the .gettext() method.

Not sure what is going on any help is appreciated.

```
package inventoryprogrampart6;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class AddItemWin extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  private int itNm,unitNm,yr;
  private String prodName;
  private double price;
    /**
     * Creates new form AddItemWin
     */
    public AddItemWin() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        textField1 = new java.awt.TextField();
        textField2 = new java.awt.TextField();
        textField3 = new java.awt.TextField();
        textField4 = new java.awt.TextField();
        textField5 = new java.awt.TextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Add New Item", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 12))); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setText("Item Number:");

        jLabel2.setText("Product Name:");

        jLabel3.setText("Number of Units:");

        jLabel4.setText("Prodcut Price");

        jLabel5.setText("Year Made:");

        jButton1.setText("Add Item");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 166, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(157, 157, 157)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(156, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                    .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3))
                            .addComponent(textField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4))
                    .addComponent(textField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(textField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(76, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       textField5.setText(String.valueOf(getitNm())); 


    }                                        

   public void addToArray()
   {
        itNm = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
        prodName = (textField2.getText());
        unitNm = Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText());
        price = Double.parseDouble(textField4.getText());
        yr = Integer.parseInt(textField5.getText());


   }


    public int getitNm()
    {
        return itNm;
    }

    public String getProdName()
    {
        return prodName;
    }
    public int getunitNm()
    {
        return unitNm;
    }
    public double getprice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    public int getyear()
    {
        return yr;
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private java.awt.TextField textField1;
    private java.awt.TextField textField2;
    private java.awt.TextField textField3;
    private java.awt.TextField textField4;
    private java.awt.TextField textField5;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you set the `itNm` value anywhere in you code?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I attempted to use a set itNm followed by the get itNm but the didn't work, I have also tried calling the addToArray within the button but that doesn't work either. I have looked many different places and feel like i am missing something basic.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling this method anywhere in your class

```
 public void addToArray()
```

That is why the values which you enter are not stored

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need all that extra code, it just wastes memory. Take out the package names when instantiating a type. Second, you can't just parse for certain text right out of a text field, you have to put the value in a string first. If that doesn't work try

```
 myTextBox.setEnabled(true);
```

If you need any more help ask me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems, mostly revolving around issues with not actually know what it is you are trying to achieve...

This will cause an error if any of the fields has no text (or text that can't be paresed as a `int`)

```
public void addToArray() {
    itNm = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
    prodName = (textField2.getText());
    unitNm = Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText());
    price = Double.parseDouble(textField4.getText());
    yr = Integer.parseInt(textField5.getText());
}
```

This means, if you leave the last field blank, it through a `NumberFormatException`.  Now, the fact that you want to copy the contents of this first field to the last field makes me wounder why you want the contents for this field.

In you `jButton1ActionPerformed` method, you could simply use `textField5.setText(textField1.getText())` and achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, this section is really used as a test. What I am attempting to do overall is I have a another GUI where if a person hits add they will be able to enter in a new product, hence the addToArray. What I want to happen is when I hit the add button for it to update the other GUI. I can list the code for that as if it helps. I am doing this right now because I realized it wasn't working on the other GUI so I tried a test to see if what I entered would pop up at all and it did not. Been trying to retrieve user input ever sense tried several different ways.

Comment: If you would like me update code or re-post I would be happy to. I could use all the help I can get.

Comment: It would suggest you take a look at [how to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)